LSTM Model doesn't train
I am trying to find the chemical state of a particle with deep learning. As inputs I have the position of the particle according to time in X_train with shape (num_train,sequence_length). (My sequence length is 100), the ouput is the frame of transition (between 1 and 100) contained in Y_train of shape (num_train,1).
Here is an example of a sequence  (https://i.sstatic.net/Ddmhjc24.jpg) with the transition at frame 84.
All of the data is generated with a very specific algorithm, however the algorithm doesn't generate very complex data, and I think it's easy to find the transition by myself, but I want this deep learning model to work.
Here is the LSTM Code :
# Filtering

# Définir le modèle LSTM
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(64, input_shape=(sequence_length, 1), return_sequences=False),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

# Compiler le modèle
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')  # Mean Squared Error pour une régression

# Afficher le résumé du modèle
model.summary()

# Entraîner le modèle
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

# Exemple de prédiction sur une nouvelle donnée
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(prediction)

The results :
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 64)                16896     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                4160      
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 21121 (82.50 KB)
Trainable params: 21121 (82.50 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
631/631 [==============================] - 35s 50ms/step - loss: 1043.6710 - val_loss: 840.6771
Epoch 2/10
631/631 [==============================] - 30s 48ms/step - loss: 840.9444 - val_loss: 839.9596
Epoch 3/10
631/631 [==============================] - 32s 50ms/step - loss: 841.6289 - val_loss: 840.7188
Epoch 4/10
631/631 [==============================] - 30s 48ms/step - loss: 840.9946 - val_loss: 840.6344
Epoch 5/10
631/631 [==============================] - 33s 52ms/step - loss: 841.8745 - val_loss: 839.9298
Epoch 6/10
631/631 [==============================] - 31s 49ms/step - loss: 841.6499 - val_loss: 839.8434
Epoch 7/10
631/631 [==============================] - 31s 49ms/step - loss: 841.2045 - val_loss: 840.0717
Epoch 8/10
631/631 [==============================] - 30s 48ms/step - loss: 842.0576 - val_loss: 840.2137
Epoch 9/10
631/631 [==============================] - 33s 52ms/step - loss: 842.7056 - val_loss: 840.5657
Epoch 10/10
631/631 [==============================] - 30s 48ms/step - loss: 841.5714 - val_loss: 839.8404
70/70 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step
[[52.569366]
 [52.569286]
 [52.569378]
 ...
 [52.569344]
 [52.569313]
 [52.56937 ]]

As you can see, the output is the same whatever the input is when I test the trained model. The val_loss doesn't improve with the number of epochs. And this is the problem, I don't understand what happens.
I triple checked my data, X_train is normalized, and I tried to add some drop out, and other layers on my model but nothing changes.
Maybe there is no possibility to do this with LSTM, but I think the data is very simple. I really want to try to find a way to use deep learning to find this.

Hi! Could you please be more specific in what exact problem your net designed to solve? And why you made a decsion to use a sequential rnn model. Besides that it would be helpfull if could provide x.head(5) output in order to see what data sits in your dataset

I assume this is keras?  You probably want to include the package you're using for the analysis in your tags.  There isn't much numpy related here - at least until you (probably) want a window function on your input.

There may be different reasons for the model not learning properly...

Guarantee yourself the number of datapoints you have is enough for the parameters of your model, its complexity and the complexity of the signal you are trying to extract
Try to provide the data in a convolutional format (see here) and with both standardised input and output (you can do this via min max normalisation).
Play with different batch sizes to allow your stateless model to better interpret your data patterns globally for all batches. In some cases i saw better results with batch sizes that span enough to consider a wide enough sample that has recurrent charactersitics (given mine is a timeseries prediction problem).
Play with different units and model configurations backed by a reasonable idea on extracting, refining and predicting potentials

Hope it helps. Lot of times is a backwards feeding loop for improval on your problem understanding, framing and codebase layout.
